# What might be another way to test if int is 32 bits wide at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, template, integer, assertions

Below is code that will compile when `INT_MAX` is equal to 2<sup>32</sup>. It will generate a compiler error when `INT_MAX` is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

namespace NBitCheck
{
    template<bool> struct CTAssert;
    template<> struct CTAssert<true> {};

    constexpr bool intbitwidthcheck=INT_MAX-(2^32)+1;
    CTAssert<intbitwidthcheck> a;
}

int main(void) {

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, `sizeof` returns the size of a number relative to the size of char.

So, `sizeof(int)` should give you how many chars each int takes.

Next, we need to know how many bits each char has. `CHAR_BIT` has that information.

So try this:

```
constexpr size_t bits_per_int = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;
constexpr bool intbitwidthcheck = (bits_per_int == 32);
```

Frankly, I believe this way is more readable.

Not to mention, can one reasonably expect a 32-bits **signed** int to contain values up to `2^32 - 1`? Shouldn't that be the `UINT_MAX`? `INT_MAX` should be up to `2^31 - 1`.

Comment: One may expect (even though I never saw such architecture) that `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX` as a border case. What the standard ensures is that `The range of non-negative values of a signed integer type is a
subrange of the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value representation of each corresponding
signed/unsigned type shall be the same.`

Comment: horrible C-style hack. Why not use the C++ features explicitly provided for such purposes? (`std::numeric_limits<>`)

Comment: @Walter numeric_limits doesn't tell how many bits an int has. If instead of checking how many bits there are you really want the actual representable limits, use Massimiliano's approach instead.

Comment: Padding bits are also included in the sizeof result… (plus what @Massimiliano said)

Answer (score 6):

To check if the fundamental type `int` is 32 bits wide I would do the following:

```
#include<limits>
#include<cstdint>

static_assert( std::numeric_limits<int>::max() == std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max() , "int is not 32 bits wide");
```

which should be (to the best of my understanding) safer than what is proposed by @luiscubal.

The point I would raise with the accepted answer is that *not all the bits in the object representation of an `int` may be used to represent a numeric value*.

In fact, even though in the C++ standard (section 3.9) the issue is not clearly stated as in the C standard (section 6.2.6.2), I think the possibility of having padding bits in an integer type representation is allowed for compatibility reasons.